# Unity3D signal 11 SIGSEGV code 1 SEGV_MAPERR, crashes on low end android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

**Crashes on low end androids, works fine on medium to high end(s6 upwards), same crash on iphone 7. Not sure what the problem is. Crashes in relatively same area each time. Game runs, then as I get closer to a denser area of meshes crash happens.**

```
 Build fingerprint: samsung/gt58wifixx/gt58wifi:6.0.1/MMB29M/T350XXU1BPK1:user/release-keys'  
08-14 14:56:52.935   379   379 F DEBUG   : Revision: '4'  
08-14 14:56:52.935   379   379 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'  
08-14 14:56:52.935   379   379 F DEBUG   : pid: 25670, tid: 25683, name: UnityMain  >>> com.test.vroom <<<  
08-14 14:56:52.935   379   379 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x3eb53096  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     r0 3eb53092  r1 00000016  r2 3eb53092  r3 00000003  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     r4 b856f218  r5 00000818  r6 00000004  r7 c0000000  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     r8 b6cc2eb8  r9 b30dcdd4  sl 00000001  fp b9fbc34c  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     ip 41a128a8  sp b30dcce0  lr 00000000  pc b6c8f7c4  cpsr 00070030  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   : backtrace:  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000307c4  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1155)  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00118844  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0011c5b4  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00ed9f54  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.985   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00ed9e98  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00e712c4  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00e7133c  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00e6d870  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 00e6ad08  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00d507b4  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00469b28  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 0034d5f8  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 006340fc  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 006365f0  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/lib/arm/libunity.so  
08-14 14:56:52.995   379   379 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 0002c2d1  /data/app/com.ecocarrier.vroom-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x21000)  
08-14 14:56:54.515  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ecocarrier.vroom/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity  
08-14 14:56:54.515   379   379 F DEBUG   :  
08-14 14:56:54.515   379   379 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03  
08-14 14:56:54.515   379   379 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:978)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:1361)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:4876)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:4553)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:5180)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17976)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:17848)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:18625)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:18125)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 W ActivityManager:       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)  
08-14 14:56:54.575  1657 26267 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()  
08-14 14:56:54.615  1657 26267 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 showBtnBg = 0 ?mcc?mnc en_CA ldltr sw768dp w768dp h1000dp 160dpi xlrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.29}    
08-14 14:56:54.705  1657  3140 I ActivityManager: Process com.ecocarrier.vroom (pid 25670)(adj 1) has died(211,559)  
08-14 14:56:54.705  1657  3140 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 25670  
08-14 14:56:54.715  1657  3140 D ActivityManager: removeProcessNameLocked mProcessNames.remove pid=25670 ,hash=259388490 ,name=com.ecocarrier.vroom  
08-14 14:56:54.715  1657  3140 D ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.ecocarrier.vroom, Auto Run ON  
08-14 14:56:54.745  1657  2685 I ActivityManager: Killing 23071:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a99 (adj 15): empty for 1914s  
08-14 14:56:54.825  1657  1680 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() true  
08-14 14:56:54.905  1657  2664 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 23071  
08-14 14:56:54.905  1657  2664 D ActivityManager: isAutoRunBlockedApp:: com.google.android.apps.photos, Auto Run ON  
08-14 14:56:54.905  1657  2664 D ActivityManager: removeProcessNameLocked mProcessNames.remove pid=23071 ,hash=198068421 ,name=com.google.android.apps.photos  
08-14 14:56:54.935  1657  1901 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a null found that would crash the game. Null was from mesh having more materials assigned than mesh actually had.

Comment: Just to help the next person who ends up here, the Android docs have a useful page on diagnosing native crashes, including spotting null dereferencing: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash